# fancybox iframe video-js on ipad/phone

Tags: fancybox

I use fancybox 2.1.5 all over our website. Some popups include an iframe with video on it, player is video-js. This works all well on Mac, Windows, Android with all browers. BUT (isn't there always a "but"?) not well on the iPad and iPhone. Here all video iframe popups are short in height (about 150px), while the popup has the usual 800px wide. The video appears proportional to that height, hence too small.

This is the fancybox code on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> /* videopopup */
$(document).ready(function () {
$.fancybox({
'width': '800px',
'autoScale': true,
'transitionIn': 'fade',
'transitionOut': 'fade',
'type': 'iframe',
'href': 'video/simpleshow.html'
});
});
</script>
```

It also makes no difference without autoscale (or autoscale 'false') or with a height defined. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. On the html page thats loaded into the iframe I put style="width:700px; height:380px" directly into the video tag

```
 <video style="width:700px; height: 393px;"
```

This solved the problem on the iPad